# One page Website

Tags: html, web

How they made one page scrolling website: http://www.creativejin.com/

With effects, and Scrolling. with mouse only!
They are using gif images but their position moves with scrolling!

This is a awesome idea but i am not sure how they made and what's the base behind it, Anyone give me a clue for it please?

Maybe my answer is overscroll.js but anyone please explain a bit?

```
  /*jslint onevar: true, strict: true */

     /*global window, document, setTimeout, clearTimeout, jQuery */

        (function(global, dom, browser, math, wait, cancel, namespace, $, none){

// We want to run this plug-in in strict-mode
// so that we may benefit from any optimizations
// strict execution
'use strict';

// The key used to bind-instance specific data to an object
var datakey = 'overscroll',

// runs feature detection for overscroll
compat = (function(){
    var b  = $.browser, fallback,
    agent = browser.userAgent,
    style  = dom.createElement(datakey).style,
    prefix = b.webkit ? 'webkit' : (b.mozilla ? 'moz' : (b.msie ? 'ms' : (b.opera ? 'o' : ''))),
    cssprefix = prefix ? ['-','-'].join(prefix) : '';
    compat = { prefix: prefix, overflowScrolling: false };
    $.each(prefix ? [prefix, ''] : [prefix], function(i, prefix){
        var animator = prefix ? (prefix + 'RequestAnimationFrame') : 'requestAnimationFrame',
        scroller = prefix ? (prefix + 'OverflowScrolling') : 'overflowScrolling';

        // check to see if requestAnimationFrame is available
        if (global[animator] !== none) {
            compat.animate = function(callback){
                global[animator].call(global, callback);
            };
        }

        // check to see if overflowScrolling is available
        if (style[scroller] !== none) {
            // Chrome 19 introduced overflow scrolling. Unfortunately, their touch
            // implementation is incomplete. Hence, we act like it is not supported
            // for chrome. #59
            if (agent.indexOf('Chrome') < 0) {
                compat.overflowScrolling = cssprefix + 'overflow-scrolling';
            }
        }
    });

    // check to see if the client supports touch
    compat.touchEvents = 'ontouchstart' in global;

    // fallback to set timeout for no animation support
    if (!compat.animate) {
        compat.animate = function(callback) {
            wait(callback, 1000/60);
        };
    }

    // firefox and webkit browsers support native grabbing cursors
    if (prefix === 'moz' || prefix === 'webkit') {
        compat.cursorGrab     = cssprefix + 'grab';
        compat.cursorGrabbing = cssprefix + 'grabbing';

    // other browsers can user google's assets
    } else {
        fallback = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/';
        compat.cursorGrab     = 'url('+fallback+'openhand.cur), default';
        compat.cursorGrabbing = 'url('+fallback+'closedhand.cur), default';
    }
    return compat;
})(),

// These are all the events that could possibly
// be used by the plug-in
events = {
    drag:       'mousemove touchmove',
    end:        'mouseup mouseleave click touchend touchcancel',
    hover:      'mouseenter mouseleave',
    ignored:    'select dragstart drag',
    scroll:     'scroll',
    start:      'mousedown touchstart',
    wheel:      'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll'
},

// These settings are used to tweak drift settings
// for the plug-in
settings = {
    captureThreshold:   3,
    driftDecay:         1.1,
    driftSequences:     22,
    driftTimeout:       100,
    scrollDelta:        15,
    thumbOpacity:       0.7,
    thumbThickness:     6,
    thumbTimeout:       400,
    wheelDelta:         20
},

// These defaults are used to complement any options
// passed into the plug-in entry point
defaults = {
    cancelOn:       'select,input,textarea',
    direction:      'multi',
    dragHold:       false,
    hoverThumbs:    false,
    scrollDelta:    settings.scrollDelta,
    showThumbs:     true,
    persistThumbs:  false,
    wheelDelta:     settings.wheelDelta,
    wheelDirection: 'vertical',
    zIndex:         999
},

// Triggers a DOM event on the overscrolled element.
// All events are namespaced under the overscroll name
triggerEvent = function (event, target) {
    target.trigger('overscroll:' + event);
},

// Utility function to return a timestamp
time = function() {
    return (new Date()).getTime();
},

// Captures the position from an event, modifies the properties
// of the second argument to persist the position, and then
// returns the modified object
capturePosition = function (event, position, index) {
    position.x = event.pageX;
    position.y = event.pageY;
    position.time = time();
    position.index = index;
    return position;
},

// Used to move the thumbs around an overscrolled element
moveThumbs = function (thumbs, sizing, left, top) {

    var ml, mt;

    if (thumbs && thumbs.added) {
        if (thumbs.horizontal) {
            ml = left * (1 + sizing.container.width / sizing.container.scrollWidth);
            mt = top + sizing.thumbs.horizontal.top;
            thumbs.horizontal.css('margin', mt + 'px 0 0 ' + ml + 'px');
        }
        if (thumbs.vertical) {
            ml = left + sizing.thumbs.vertical.left;
            mt = top * (1 + sizing.container.height / sizing.container.scrollHeight);
            thumbs.vertical.css('margin', mt + 'px 0 0 ' + ml + 'px');
        }
    }

},

// Used to toggle the thumbs on and off
// of an overscrolled element
toggleThumbs = function (thumbs, options, dragging) {
    if (thumbs && thumbs.added && !options.persistThumbs) {
        if (dragging) {
            if (thumbs.vertical) {
                thumbs.vertical.stop(true, true).fadeTo('fast', settings.thumbOpacity);
            }
            if (thumbs.horizontal) {
                thumbs.horizontal.stop(true, true).fadeTo('fast', settings.thumbOpacity);
            }
        } else {
            if (thumbs.vertical) {
                thumbs.vertical.fadeTo('fast', 0);
            }
            if (thumbs.horizontal) {
                thumbs.horizontal.fadeTo('fast', 0);
            }
        }
    }
},

// Defers click event listeners to after a mouseup event.
// Used to avoid unintentional clicks
deferClick = function (target) {
    var clicks, key = 'events';
    var events = $._data ? $._data(target[0], key) : target.data(key);
    if (events && events.click) {
        clicks = events.click.slice();
        target.off('click').one('click', function(event){
            $.each(clicks, function(i, click){
                target.click(click);
            }); return false;
        });
    }
},

// Toggles thumbs on hover. This event is only triggered
// if the hoverThumbs option is set
hover = function (event) {
    var data = event.data,
    thumbs   = data.thumbs,
    options  = data.options,
    dragging = event.type === 'mouseenter';
    toggleThumbs(thumbs, options, dragging);
},

// This function is only ever used when the overscrolled element
// scrolled outside of the scope of this plugin.
scroll = function (event) {
    var data = event.data;
    if (!data.flags.dragged) {
        moveThumbs(data.thumbs, data.sizing, this.scrollLeft, this.scrollTop);
    }
},

// handles mouse wheel scroll events
wheel = function (event) {

    // prevent any default wheel behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = event.data,
    options = data.options,
    sizing = data.sizing,
    thumbs = data.thumbs,
    wheel = data.wheel,
    flags = data.flags, delta,
    original = event.originalEvent;

    // stop any drifts
    flags.drifting = false;

    // calculate how much to move the viewport by
    // TODO: let's base this on some fact somewhere...
    if (original.wheelDelta) {
        delta = original.wheelDelta / (compat.prefix === 'o' ? -120 : 120);
    } if (original.detail) {
        delta = -original.detail / 3;
    } delta *= options.wheelDelta;

    // initialize flags if this is the first tick
    if (!wheel) {
        data.target.data(datakey).dragging = flags.dragging = true;
        data.wheel = wheel = { timeout: null };
        toggleThumbs(thumbs, options, true);
    }

    // actually modify scroll offsets
    if (options.wheelDirection === 'horizontal') {
        this.scrollLeft -= delta;
    } else {
        this.scrollTop -= delta;
    }

    if (wheel.timeout) { cancel(wheel.timeout); }

    moveThumbs(thumbs, sizing, this.scrollLeft, this.scrollTop);

    wheel.timeout = wait(function() {
        data.target.data(datakey).dragging = flags.dragging = false;
        toggleThumbs(thumbs, options, data.wheel = null);
    }, settings.thumbTimeout);

},

// updates the current scroll offset during a mouse move
drag = function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var data = event.data,
    touches  = event.originalEvent.touches,
    options  = data.options,
    sizing   = data.sizing,
    thumbs   = data.thumbs,
    position = data.position,
    flags    = data.flags,
    target   = data.target.get(0);


    // correct page coordinates for touch devices
    if (compat.touchEvents && touches && touches.length) {
        event = touches[0];
    }

    if (!flags.dragged) {
        toggleThumbs(thumbs, options, true);
    }

    flags.dragged = true;

    if (options.direction !== 'vertical') {
        target.scrollLeft -= (event.pageX - position.x);
    }

    if (data.options.direction !== 'horizontal') {
        target.scrollTop -= (event.pageY - position.y);
    }

    capturePosition(event, data.position);

    if (--data.capture.index <= 0) {
        data.target.data(datakey).dragging = flags.dragging = true;
        capturePosition(event, data.capture, settings.captureThreshold);
    }

    moveThumbs(thumbs, sizing, target.scrollLeft, target.scrollTop);

},

// sends the overscrolled element into a drift
drift = function (target, event, callback) {

    var data   = event.data, dx, dy, xMod, yMod,
    capture    = data.capture,
    options    = data.options,
    sizing     = data.sizing,
    thumbs     = data.thumbs,
    elapsed    = time() - capture.time,
    scrollLeft = target.scrollLeft,
    scrollTop  = target.scrollTop,
    decay      = settings.driftDecay;

    // only drift if enough time has passed since
    // the last capture event
    if (elapsed > settings.driftTimeout) {
        return callback(data);
    }

    // determine offset between last capture and current time
    dx = options.scrollDelta * (event.pageX - capture.x);
    dy = options.scrollDelta * (event.pageY - capture.y);

    // update target scroll offsets
    if (options.direction !== 'vertical') {
        scrollLeft -= dx;
    } if (options.direction !== 'horizontal') {
        scrollTop -= dy;
    }

    // split the distance to travel into a set of sequences
    xMod = dx / settings.driftSequences;
    yMod = dy / settings.driftSequences;

    triggerEvent('driftstart', data.target);

    data.drifting = true;

    // animate the drift sequence
    compat.animate(function render() {
        if (data.drifting) {
            var min = 1, max = -1;
            data.drifting = false;
            if (yMod > min && target.scrollTop > scrollTop || yMod < max && target.scrollTop < scrollTop) {
                data.drifting = true;
                target.scrollTop -= yMod;
                yMod /= decay;
            }
            if (xMod > min && target.scrollLeft > scrollLeft || xMod < max && target.scrollLeft < scrollLeft) {
                data.drifting = true;
                target.scrollLeft -= xMod;
                xMod /= decay;
            }
            moveThumbs(thumbs, sizing, target.scrollLeft, target.scrollTop);
            compat.animate(render);
        } else {
            triggerEvent('driftend', data.target);
            callback(data);
        }
    });

},

// starts the drag operation and binds the mouse move handler
start = function (event) {

    var data = event.data,
    target   = data.target,
    start    = data.start = $(event.target),
    flags    = data.flags;

    // stop any drifts
    flags.drifting = false;

    // only start drag if the user has not explictly banned it.
    if (start.size() && !start.is(data.options.cancelOn)) {

        // without this the simple "click" event won't be recognized on touch clients
        if (!compat.touchEvents) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        target.css('cursor', compat.cursorGrabbing);
        target.data(datakey).dragging = flags.dragging = flags.dragged = false;

        // apply the drag listeners to the doc or target
        if(data.options.dragHold) {
            $(document).on(events.drag, data, drag);
        } else {
            target.on(events.drag, data, drag);
        }

        data.position = capturePosition(event, {});
        data.capture = capturePosition(event, {}, settings.captureThreshold);
        triggerEvent('dragstart', target);
    }

},

// ends the drag operation and unbinds the mouse move handler
stop = function (event) {

    var data = event.data,
    target = data.target,
    options = data.options,
    flags = data.flags,
    thumbs = data.thumbs,

    // hides the thumbs after the animation is done
    done = function () {
        if (thumbs && !options.hoverThumbs) {
            toggleThumbs(thumbs, options, false);
        }
    };

    // remove drag listeners from doc or target
    if(options.dragHold) {
        $(document).unbind(events.drag, drag);
    } else {
        target.unbind(events.drag, drag);
    }

    // only fire events and drift if we started with a
    // valid position
    if (data.position) {

        triggerEvent('dragend', target);

        // only drift if a drag passed our threshold
        if (flags.dragging) {
            drift(target.get(0), event, done);
        } else {
            done();
        }

    }

    // only if we moved, and the mouse down is the same as
    // the mouse up target do we defer the event
    if (flags.dragging && data.start.is(event.target)) {
        deferClick(data.start);
    }

    // clear all internal flags and settings
    target.data(datakey).dragging =
        data.start     =
        data.capture   =
        data.position  =
        flags.dragged  =
        flags.dragging = false;

    // set the cursor back to normal
    target.css('cursor', compat.cursorGrab);

},

// Ensures that a full set of options are provided
// for the plug-in. Also does some validation
getOptions = function(options) {

    // fill in missing values with defaults
    options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    // check for inconsistent directional restrictions
    if (options.direction !== 'multi' && options.direction !== options.wheelDirection) {
        options.wheelDirection = options.direction;
    }

    // ensure positive values for deltas
    options.scrollDelta = math.abs(options.scrollDelta);
    options.wheelDelta  = math.abs(options.wheelDelta);

    // fix values for scroll offset
    options.scrollLeft = options.scrollLeft === none ? null : math.abs(options.scrollLeft);
    options.scrollTop  = options.scrollTop  === none ? null : math.abs(options.scrollTop);

    return options;

},

// Returns the sizing information (bounding box) for the
// target DOM element
getSizing = function (target) {

    var $target  = $(target),
    width        = $target.width(),
    height       = $target.height(),
    scrollWidth  = width >= target.scrollWidth ? width : target.scrollWidth,
    scrollHeight = height >= target.scrollHeight ? height : target.scrollHeight,
    hasScroll    = scrollWidth > width || scrollHeight > height;

    return {
        valid: hasScroll,
        container: {
            width: width,
            height: height,
            scrollWidth: scrollWidth,
            scrollHeight: scrollHeight
        },
        thumbs: {
            horizontal: {
                width: width * width / scrollWidth,
                height: settings.thumbThickness,
                corner: settings.thumbThickness / 2,
                left: 0,
                top: height - settings.thumbThickness
            },
            vertical: {
                width: settings.thumbThickness,
                height: height * height / scrollHeight,
                corner: settings.thumbThickness / 2,
                left: width - settings.thumbThickness,
                top: 0
            }
        }
    };

},

// Attempts to get (or implicitly creates) the
// remover function for the target passed
// in as an argument
getRemover = function (target, orCreate) {

    var $target = $(target), thumbs,
    data        = $target.data(datakey) || {},
    style       = $target.attr('style'),
    fallback    = orCreate ? function () {

        data = $target.data(datakey);
        thumbs = data.thumbs;

        // restore original styles (if any)
        if (style) {
            $target.attr('style', style);
        } else {
            $target.removeAttr('style');
        }

        // remove any created thumbs
        if (thumbs) {
            if (thumbs.horizontal) { thumbs.horizontal.remove(); }
            if (thumbs.vertical)   { thumbs.vertical.remove();   }
        }

        // remove any bound overscroll events and data
        $target
            .removeData(datakey)
            .off(events.wheel,      wheel)
            .off(events.start,      start)
            .off(events.end,        stop)
            .off(events.ignored,    false);

    } : $.noop;

    return $.isFunction(data.remover) ? data.remover : fallback;

},

// Genterates CSS specific to a particular thumb.
// It requires sizing data and options
getThumbCss = function(size, options) {
    return {
        position: 'absolute',
        opacity: options.persistThumbs ? settings.thumbOpacity : 0,
        'background-color': 'red',
        width: size.width + 'px',
        height: size.height + 'px',
        'border-radius': size.corner + 'px',
        'margin': size.top + 'px 0 0 ' + size.left + 'px',
        'z-index': options.zIndex
    };
},

// Creates the DOM elements used as "thumbs" within
// the target container.
createThumbs = function(target, sizing, options) {

    var div = '<div/>',
    thumbs  = {},
    css     = false;

    if (sizing.container.scrollWidth > 0 && options.direction !== 'vertical') {
        css = getThumbCss(sizing.thumbs.horizontal, options);
        thumbs.horizontal = $(div).css(css).prependTo(target);
    }

    if (sizing.container.scrollHeight > 0 && options.direction !== 'horizontal') {
        css = getThumbCss(sizing.thumbs.vertical, options);
        thumbs.vertical = $(div).css(css).prependTo(target);
    }

    thumbs.added = !!css;

    return thumbs;

},

// This function takes a jQuery element, some
// (optional) options, and sets up event metadata
// for each instance the plug-in affects
setup = function(target, options) {

    // create initial data properties for this instance
    options = getOptions(options);
    var sizing = getSizing(target),
    thumbs, data = {
        options: options, sizing: sizing,
        flags: { dragging: false },
        remover: getRemover(target, true)
    };

    // only apply handlers if the overscrolled element
    // actually has an area to scroll
    if (sizing.valid) {
        // provide a circular-reference, enable events, and
        // apply any required CSS
        data.target = target = $(target).css({
            position: 'relative',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            cursor: compat.cursorGrab
        }).on(events.wheel, data, wheel)
          .on(events.start, data, start)
          .on(events.end, data, stop)
          .on(events.scroll, data, scroll)
          .on(events.ignored, false);

        // apply the stop listeners for drag end
        if(options.dragHold) {
            $(document).on(events.end, data, stop);
        } else {
            data.target.on(events.end, data, stop);
        }

        // apply any user-provided scroll offsets
        if (options.scrollLeft !== null) {
            target.scrollLeft(options.scrollLeft);
        } if (options.scrollTop !== null) {
            target.scrollTop(options.scrollTop);
        }

        // add thumbs and listeners (if we're showing them)
        if (options.showThumbs) {
            data.thumbs = thumbs = createThumbs(target, sizing, options);
            if (thumbs.added) {
                moveThumbs(thumbs, sizing, target.scrollLeft(), target.scrollTop());
                if (options.hoverThumbs) {
                    target.on(events.hover, data, hover);
                }
            }
        }

        target.data(datakey, data);
    }

},

// Removes any event listeners and other instance-specific
// data from the target. It attempts to leave the target
// at the state it found it.
teardown = function(target) {
    getRemover(target)();
},

// This is the entry-point for enabling the plug-in;
// You can find it's exposure point at the end
// of this closure
overscroll = function(options) {
    return this.removeOverscroll().each(function() {
        setup(this, options);
    });
},

// This function applies touch-specific CSS to enable
// the behavior that Overscroll emulates. This function is
// called instead of overscroll if the device supports it
touchscroll = function(options) {
    return this.removeOverscroll().each(function() {
        var target = $(this).data(datakey, {
            remover: getRemover(this)
        }).css(compat.overflowScrolling, 'touch')
          .css('overflow', 'auto');
        options = getOptions(options);
        if (options.scrollLeft !== null) {
            target.scrollLeft(options.scrollLeft);
        } if (options.scrollTop !== null) {
            target.scrollTop(options.scrollTop);
        }
    });
},

// This is the entry-point for disabling the plug-in;
// You can find it's exposure point at the end
// of this closure
removeOverscroll = function() {
    return this.each(function () {
        teardown(this);
    });
};

// Extend overscroll to expose settings to the user
overscroll.settings = settings;

// Extend jQuery's prototype to expose the plug-in.
// If the supports native overflowScrolling, overscroll will not
// attempt to override the browser's built in support
$.extend(namespace, {
    overscroll:         compat.overflowScrolling ? touchscroll : overscroll,
    removeOverscroll:   removeOverscroll
});

 })(window, document, navigator, Math, setTimeout, clearTimeout, jQuery.fn, jQuery);
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Cool idea as it may be, what have you already tried?

Comment: Copying the overscroll source code verbatim does not count as sharing what you've tried and only makes it seem less likely that you thoroughly investigated your question.

Comment: It is pretty but it does not work too well on a mobile device I've noticed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use [jQuery Overscroll](http://www.azoffdesign.com/overscroll). In the source you can see that they have the `<div class="wrap">` 
and the [background image](http://www.creativejin.com/images/bg.gif) is attached to `<div id="content">`. For the selector `$(".wrap")` the overscroll plugin is attached:

```
o = $(".wrap").overscroll({
    cancelOn: '.fields, #map',
    scrollLeft: scrollX,
    scrollTop: scrollY
}).on('overscroll:dragstart overscroll:dragend 
          overscroll:driftstart overscroll:driftend'
       ,function (event) {}
);
```

To get started take a look at the [github page for overscroll](https://github.com/azoff/Overscroll)

Comment: Thank you for the deep analysis, I also figure out the same and this is made for mobile versions only as its very useful for mobile applications. also, threeFourOneSixOneThree i commented on your answer on my question with details at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830801/javascript-click-event-issue

i hope you checked it and help with it. Many thanks!