# JavaScript click event issue

Tags: javascript, html, image

On my page are two images that are both visible initially

- one is a rich graphic
- the other is a transparent blank image

When a user clicks on the transparent image the rich graphic is hidden.
When the user clicks on the rich graphic the rich graphic is hidden again.

My problem is that currently the rich graphic is not shown after the user has clicked on the transparent blank image. Below is what code i've tried so far.

HTML

```
 <div id="change">
 <img src="image-visable.png">
 <img src="image-hidden.png">
          </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var port_change, i;
window.onload = function () {

    port_change = document.getElementById("change").getElementsByTagName("change");

    for (i = 0; i < port_change.length; i++) {
        port_change[i].style.display = "";

        port_change[i].onclick = (function (k) {
            var r = function () {
                this.style.display = "none";
                if (k >= port_change.length) { k = 0 }
                port_change[k].style.display = "none";
            };
            return r;
        })(i+1);
    }

    port_change[0].style.display = "";
}
```

**PEN**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hbcze
Any idea?

Comment: You may take a look at this answer [toggle visibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642422/javascrip-toggle-visibility-multiple-divs#17642589)

Comment: `getElementsByTagName("change")` is that a typo?

Comment: Check this pen please: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hbcze

Maybe i am not good in explaining my problem :(

Comment: Red button visible all the time, ( As red button is my transparent image ) When guest come to my site, He see two buttons, Red and blue, If he click on red OR blue button then blue button should hide. and when blue button is hide, he click the red button again to see the blue button. red click, blue hidden, blue click blue hidden, ..In other words, If guest click on red or blue button, Blue should hide and show again when red clicked!

Comment: Please take a look at my 3rd update. The coding was easy - it was difficult to understand what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Toggle visibility of element

[...] removed to keep the post short - see history and / or the **[working demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fmGDq)**

#### Update to address some parts of your code

The part `.getElementsByTagName("change")` should very likely be .getElementsByTagName("img").
Some properties (display) were set multiple times. So i rewrote your code like this

```
function setHideHandler()
{
    return function () { 
       console.log("this", this);
       this.style.display = "none";                    
    };      
}

function setOnLoad(){           
    var image;              
    var port_change = document.getElementById("change").getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (i = 0; i < port_change.length; i++) {              
        image = port_change[i];         
        image.style.display = "";           
        image.onclick = setHideHandler();
    }
}
```

With this html

```
<div id="change">
  <img id=t src="t.png" />
  <img id=g src="g.png" />
</div>
```

So now you can see that you set up an onclick handler to hide the image after it has been clicked. After the user has clicked on any image (g or t) the code hides this image. After both images were clicked the user has no option to click on anything to redisplay the other image.

So therefore you must find a way to crosswire them. If user clicks on t then g is shown and t is hidden. Now that g is visible the user can click g to hide it and you must show t again.

This is the complete code

```
function showOther(el){
  if(el.nextElementSibling){
    sibling = el.nextElementSibling;
  }else if(el.previousElementSibling){
    sibling = el.previousElementSibling;    
  }
  sibling.style.display ='';
  el.style.display = 'none';
}

function setHideHandler() {
    return function () {                     
       showOther(this);                 
    };      
}

function setOnLoad(){           
    var image;              
var port_change = document.getElementById("change").getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (i = 0; i < port_change.length; i++) {              
        image = port_change[i];         
        image.style.display = "";           
        image.onclick = setHideHandler();
    }
}
```

### Working example of above code

**[Another fully working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nJGjh)**

### Update 3 after your explanation

T[his example shows two images](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qhBft). The white image is always visible. If the user clicks on it the black image visibility is toggled. If the user clicks on the black image it will be hidden **[see example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qhBft)**

### Update 4 regarding your comment on `<noscript>`

You wrote: `In the DOM tree i see <noscript> And images are not switching. i removed this node But when i reload its again there. Why its coming on page HTML tree?`

```
<noscript style="display: inline;">
    &lt;img class=stay src="trans.png"/&gt;
</noscript>
```

I believe that this goes way beyond your initial question since i provided a working solution for your problem. But to give you a few hints you have to answer a few questions

- Which images are not switching after which user action? Why is this relevant for the noscript-tag?
- Are you using wordpress to create [the page we are talking about](http://jason.pixub.com/profiles/david-france-racial-disparities-in-education/)?
- How do you embed the video - do you create the html by hand or are you [using wordpress features to embed video](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds)
- If you have full control over the source code and remove something it stays removed. Since you said that you `removed the node but after a page load it is there again` i assume that you at least partially use functionality that is not 100% controled by you (similar to the wordpress link above).

**Please tell me why you did not yet accepted my answer?**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Well, as i mentioned above that both images are visible, display: ""; When i click on transparent or graphics image, it goes, But when i click it again, graphic image does't come up. As i am using transparent image in a white area to click. I hope this helps to understand in better way.

Comment: g and t are visible, As user can see g but t is a blank image. But on page both images are loaded. When guest click on g or t, g gone hidden by javascript. but t still there. when guest click on t again, g wont come up. it should come up if guest click on t. T is the white area where i am using t in 500x500 size.

Comment: Well, Above code did't work at all. I think there is no solution of it, So, i am thinking a easy solution. Is that possible to make Img T as button? I mean use image T as a button so when image T is click img G hide, and when image T again click then Img G show up. Just like a button?

Comment: 3rd Update worked! Amazing, I was unable to explain that's why it takes you to make 3 updates. Sorry for that. Finally it worked well But There is one small problem, In the DOM tree, i see <noscript style="display: inline;">&lt;img class=stay src="trans.png"/&gt;</noscript> And images are not switching, But i removed this node. (i thought its a error in page load) and its working fine. But when i reload to check its again there. why its coming on page HTML tree?

Comment: Without seeing your code I can not help. The no script part is for when there is no JavaScript, so I guess that this is the reason why the image is not switching since we need JavaScript but we do not have it.

Comment: Thank you for the update: Image G is not switching becuase of noscript thing in dom tree, and when i removed it from the dom tree from chrome inspect elements than everything works fine. and Noscript is not in my source code at all. I do not know where its is coming under the img code. 

Yes i am using wordpress and a plugin to generate that player to play media.

That noscript is making all the problem that's why your code is not working. and No problem :) You explained and teach me very well and i will accept your answer now . but plz give me a hint why no script in my code??

Comment: Nevermind! I found the issue, the js lazyload code was making the mess! i removed it and now zoomppp!! Working fine. Thank you very much for your help. You are a life saver!

Comment: I can only guess since i never used wordpress. My guess is as since you are using `a plugin to generate that player to play media.` this plugin creates the <noscript> part. I found the probable cause why my code is not working in your page. If you click on the play button of the player `<img class="stay" ` the event listener is fired `$("img.stay").on("click", function(){ ... var sibling = getSibling(this); ...` But this does not work since in your code the transparent image `<img class="toggle" ` is not a sibling. If you need more info you can ask a new question and i will help you.

Comment: Good to hear. I checked the version that is online and there is still a bug; but i assume the online version is not updated yet.